# Sugar ORM - Difference between save() and update()

Tags: android-sqlite, sugarorm

What is the difference between save() and update() in sugar ORM?

By referring to this [Sugar ORM in Android: update a saved object in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26835785/2462531)

save and update are giving same result?

I want to update the existing record if exist how to do that?

here I want to do something like:

```
 long count = Lead.count(Lead.class);
                            if (count > 0) {
                                List<Lead> leads = Lead.find(Lead.class, "lead_id = ?", leadItem.leadId);

                                if (leads == null) { // save leadItem
                                    Lead.save(lead);
                                    logFile.writeLog("Home Activity: Lead saved in local DB. Lead Id is: " + leadItem.leadId + " leadItem Name: " + leadItem.name);
                                    Log.d("Lead saved: ", leadItem.toString());
                                } else { // update leadItem
                                    Lead.update(lead);
                                    logFile.writeLog("Home Activity: Lead updated in local DB. Lead Id is: " + leadItem.leadId + " leadItem Name: " + leadItem.name);
                                    Log.d("Lead updated: ", leadItem.toString());
                                }
                            }
```

Here when I call update it is also updating the another record which I saved with different ID and adding as new record rather update.

Comment: When I am using save() method for both save and update working fine in some cases but not in all why? any solution?

Comment: Hello, OK so first of all find() returns an empty list if there are no records matching the query, so I suspect you are in fact calling update() in some situations where the record does not actually exist :).  Secondly, I would love to see how you set the id in the previous code if this doesn't help.